# New card not rendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, render

I added a feature whereby the user can add cards to the app with the following code:

```
export default function Filter({
   onChangeHogListAdd
   }) {

const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('')

function handleAdd() {
    onChangeHogListAdd(textInput)
}

return(
   <div>
        <div className ='ui item'>
            <label>Add a hog!</label>
        </div>
        <div className='ui item'>
            <input
                className='ui input focus'
                type='text'
                placeholder='Add hog...'
                onChange={(e) => setTextInput(e.target.value)}
            />
        </div>
        <div className='ui item'>
            <button className='ui button' onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
        </div>
   </div>
)
```

The callback prop in the parent component is the following

```
function hogListAdd(newName) {
    hogList.push({ name : newName })
}
```

Whereby hogList is an array of objects which is rendered as cards on the UI. Weirdly enough, when a user adds a new hog through the text input box, the array hogList updates with the newly added object, but the page doesn't render it in. This is the part that I am stuck on, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use a state variable to update data in component.. once you pushed data in hoglist assign that hoglist to state variable

Comment: @RamkumarG thank you for your insight!! The answers to this post illustrate the simple concept you mentioned :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing to `hogList`, which doesn't tell React about state change. In the parent component use `useState` hook and call the setter

```
const [hogList, setHogList] = useState([]);
function hogListAdd(newName) {
  setHogList((old) => [...old, { name : newName }]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your amazingly helpful answer, Amit! I tried out your code and it worked great for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re render the ui with updated array then you have to store it in a state and update in your function.
It can look like this

```
function hogListAdd(newName) {
    setHogList([{name : newName }, ...hogList])
    //hoglist is your state variable
}
```

Use the state where you hoglist is present so that on any change to it the component will re render.

And use that state to render ui so that your component depends on it.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Your answer totally did help Prashant!! Your code worked :)